# Is it possible to make Photoshop pixel perfect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, cs6, subpixel-rendering

As a web designer I hate one particular thing about Photoshop:

[image: half pixelz]

Is it possible to force PS CS6 to turn decimal pixels EVERYWHERE off?

I've been lurking around GD for a while now and nothing seems to work, as I don't even see Pixel Preview option anywhere. Also Edit\Preferences\Guides, Grids & Slices and setting Guideline every 1px doesn't help either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, pixel perfect does mena different thing in different usecases. Anyway the pencil tool will only color full pixels. I have no problem getting control over exact individual piuxels so care to describe your actual problem.

Comment: YES! by doing shape tool it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least when it comes to dragging out ruler guides, like you appear to be doing.

When dragging a ruler onto the canvas, **hold the shift key** and your guide will be constrained to the 'ticks' on the ruler.

So when viewing at 100%, as you drag, your guide will snap to every 10 pixel increment. You can snap to every single pixel by zooming in to 1200%, and then dragging with shift.

So holding shift means you cannot place a guide between pixels, effectively "turning off decimal pixels".

Comment: And offcourse the pixel itself is located at the 0.5 0.5 fraction not the corner. No, pixels are not [small squares](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf).