# How to prepare Photoshop to design a Website

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, measurement

I'm having some trouble finding out how to prepare Photoshop to design a Website.
When i try to program what i draw, the measurements are never correct. Always bigger.

Is there a way for me to design the website in "real" values?

Like, 10px in Photoshop being 10px in the browser.

Comment: What do you mean they are bigger? 10px in your Photoshop document (at 72 pixels/inch, the standard for digital docs) should be 10px in your browser. Are you sure you are not using a different pixel/inch measurement?

Comment: Yeah what @Yisela said. You can also use Creative Cloud Extract Service to get accurate values out of your Photoshop files: https://assets.adobe.com/link/ad7110b3-340f-4d68-9479-c8aa1b0ad25e?section=extract

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for me to design the website in "real" values?

Yes, if you design it in the browser.  If you design in Photoshop expecting 100% pixel perfection that will not happen unless you use nothing but image slices which will cause your site to have terrible load times and it would likely only work fixed for whatever you need it for, such as a desktop browser.  We have several questions similar to this:

- [Designing A Website from Scratch – Illustrator or Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/538/designing-a-website-from-scratch-illustrator-or-photoshop)
- [Is it possible to make Photoshop pixel perfect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37032/is-it-possible-to-make-photoshop-pixel-perfect)
- [What is the exact role/relationship of photoshop in web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17928/what-is-the-exact-role-relationship-of-photoshop-in-web-design?rq=1)
- [Developer to Designer path: How To](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/developer-to-designer-path-how-to)
- [What are the steps in designing a website?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36884/what-are-the-steps-in-designing-a-website)
- [What are some common mistakes that a designer can make when designing for web, and how can they be avoided](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/what-are-some-common-mistakes-that-a-designer-can-make-when-designing-for-web-a)